# MapReduce with 2 values

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to have two values in MapReduce?

My csv looks like this:

```
month,  date,  deviceCategory, totalTransactionRevenue
201608 20160801  Desktop        1000
201608 20160801  Mobile         700
```

I want to use MapReduce to calculate each kind of device's average revenue per month. I want the output be looks like this:

```
 (month, deskRev, mobileRev)
```

But when I code `context.write(month, DesktopoutPut, MobileoutPut);`in Mapper, it says cannot be applied to given types. Is it because MapReduce must in key-value pair?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to your needs you can concatenate the month and deviceCategory.
Hence you can use this as a key (this actually forms a composite key).
This key and corresponding value will look like

**<*201608 Desktop* , 1000>**

**<*201608 Mobile* , 700>**

It requires absolute no change in your program except one line to concatenate the two fields.